# Hangfire using Autofac in MVC5. IoC inject task with DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container, autofac, hangfire

I am sure this has come up before but after all of my searching I cannot find a resolution.

MVC5 application using Unity which I have configured a simple UnitOfWork where the DbContext is injected and have integrated OWIN following (http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/) All working well.

I have just added Hangfire and would like to inject my DbContext to the background task, similar to the UnitOfWork class, seemed simple enough.

Scaffolded up the task with its interface, installed hangfire and as per samples I had seen using Autofac and Autofac.Mvc5.  First cut I run it with an empty constructor all working fine.  Now add the DbContext to the constructor and remove the empty constructor and bang...

Every time the task is triggered by HangFire I get the following exception in the "State" HangFire table:

```
    {"FailedAt":"2017-06-20T03:48:25.4862236Z","ExceptionType":"Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = EmailProcess (ReflectionActivator), Services = [[AppName].Tasks.EmailProcess], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type '[AppName].Tasks.EmailProcess' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext db' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Data.Entity.DbContext)'. (See inner exception for details.)","ExceptionDetails":"Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = EmailProcess (ReflectionActivator), Services = [[AppName].Tasks.EmailProcess], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type '[AppName].Tasks.EmailProcess' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext db' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Data.Entity.DbContext)'. (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type '[AppName].Tasks.EmailProcess' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext db' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Data.Entity.DbContext)'.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at Hangfire.AutofacJobActivator.AutofacScope.Resolve(Type type)
   at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)"}
```

My configuration is as follows:

**UnityConfig.cs**

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
    #endregion

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>(); 
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(); 
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));

        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("TaskEngine");
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<EmailProcess>();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(builder.Build());

        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();

        // point task engine toi email processing
        IEmailProcess emailProcess = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<EmailProcess>();
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => emailProcess.ProcessEmailQueue(), Cron.MinuteInterval(1));
    }
}
```

**The Background Task**

```
public class EmailProcess : IEmailProcess
{

    private readonly DbContext _db;
    private readonly DbSet<EmailQueue> _emailQueue;

    /* No exception with this empty constructor in place (no _db of course)
    public EmailProcess()
    { }
    */
    public EmailProcess(DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
        _emailQueue = _db.Set<EmailQueue>();
    }

    public void ProcessEmailQueue()
    {
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not finding the registration of the db context. I see the `RegisterTypes` definition but not not seeing were/how it is being called in startup. The issue here is how the Ioc was configured. Also noticed that the registration of `EmailProcess` is registering the concrete class instead of the abstraction.

Comment: Added the extra code above to UnityConfig.cs that is called by GetConfiguredContainer() in UnityMvcActivator (nuget Unity.Mvc) at application startup (boilerplate).  Attempted to RegisterType with abstraction of EmailProcess as suggested and always exception of `Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException` EmailProcess has not been registered.

Comment: Setup as above seems to register the EmailProcess ok just can't resolve the DbContext parameter.  As stated above, install default empty constructor no error raised.

Comment: Does `ApplicationDbContext` have any explicit dependencies?

Comment: Derived from IdentityDBContext, standard aspnet boilerplate code 

 `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }`

Comment: @StephenDavies did you get it to work eventually?